# What is the diffrence between a NIC frame and an IP packet?

Tags: osi

I searched on google and it only gave me limited information on the differences. I need to know what are also the components on the two encapsulations. Not much information on IP packets except just packets.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dear you must know that there is no thing called NIC frames because NIC is OSI layer 1 device such like hubs and cables so it simple generate bits (0s and 1s) , each OSI layer generate different type of Data  called protocol data unit ***PDU*** and special device can understand it as next

- L1>>Bits (Cables,NIC,HUB)
- L2>>Frames (L2 Switches)
- L3>>Packets (L3 switches and Routers)
- L4>>**Segment** (Fire walls)
- L5:L7>>**Data** (PC and Servers)

Where each layer adds its header  on the previous PDU and generates its own PDU in the encapsulation process and vise versa in the decapsulation process
For example during the encapsulation process L5 (Data) encapsulated in L4 header and generate new PDU called Segment and during the decapsulation process L4 segment header will be striped off to get Data from it as the next

[image]

***now we can answer your question*** , each Layer add functional header to the previous layer for example L3 will add header indicate source and distination L3 address (IPs) or some times called logical address and other informations provide end to end delivery insurance and so on as next

[image]